# What's the default file path in WinRT/WP 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, sqlite-net

Hello fellow programmers.

I recently made a mistake while using the SQLite-NET package for Windows Phone 8.1. When opening a new `SQLiteConnection`, I would give as parameter to its constructor the string `"data.db"`, without being actually aware of what was going on under the hood. Later on, I noticed that the file wouldn't be deleted, even if I uninstalled the application (since I would have in my app the same entries that I had before uninstalling it); I assume that I should be using the local folder for application data instead.
However, here is the real question: what the hell is the folder where the `data.db` file was created? I tried to figure it out with the following piece of code:

```
var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///data.db"));
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(file.Path);
```

and what I got as output of the `WriteLine` method was the path

`C:\Data\SharedData\PhoneTools\AppxLayouts\f7529f24-ba24-4fdb-8353-cff9214180a0VS.Debug_ARM.Valbrand\data.db`,

which only got me even more confused. I couldn't find any satisfactory info on this, and I would REALLY like to further my understanding of what happened here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path you are looking at is the install directory of your app. You have a Silverlight 8.1 app, so the path is slightly different than a Silverlight 8.0 app, but the articles [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.applicationmodel.package.installedlocation.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402541%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) will help you get a rough understanding.

The recommended usage of this directory is to take the resources that you want backed up out of it on first run and move them to the [app data container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder.aspx), so they can be backed up by the system.

Answer (score 0):

`C:\Data\SharedData\PhoneTools\AppxLayouts\f7529f24-ba24-4fdb-8353-cff9214180a0VS.Debug_ARM.Valbrand\data.db`

This is the path on your phone/emulator.

And This is not the location where you can find in your PC.